# Unable to send an email using php on windows 8

Tags: php, html, linux, windows, xampp

I have been trying to send email using php, I am able to send email when I try to run code on Linux but unable to run it on windows 8, I have XAMPP installed on my windows. Here is the code.

```
<?php
 $msg = "Checking Email";
 $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
 mail("myemailaddress","My subject",$msg);
?>
```

I look online and found out that I have to edit php.ini and sendmail.ini file. I am not sure though that this is the right solution. If it is, can anyone please tell me what exactly do I have to edit or change it, because I tried to edit those files but it still not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would try using PHPMailer. I prefer using it over PHPs built in system. I find it less of a hassle.
Here's some of what you can do with it:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

There is more information on their [github page](http://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). And there should be no trouble setting it up if you have access to a web server, with email credentials - you would need a host not just XAMPP or LAMP (assuming you intend to get that eventually).